# Git worktrees not showing branch names, but recognizing branches

Tags: git, windows-10, zsh, wsl-2

I recently enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) on Windows 10 and installed Debian.

I also installed zsh with several plugins. You can see the dotfiles repo here: https://github.com/art3xias23/wsl-dotfiles

I'm using Windows Terminal, however there is no difference if I use gitbash and debian on their own or inside Windows Terminal.

My issue is:

I have a repo with 3 worktrees on my windows home directory.

When I use git bash for windows I can see the branch names fine after the directory.

**GitBash**

Repo1: [image]

Repo2: [image]

**ZSHELL**

Now when I move to zsh and try to access the same windows home directory worktrees, I can see the branch name for only the first repo and not the second or third (The first repo contains the .git directory)

I also don't see any other branch names, like the one for the my wsl-dotfiles repo, which is my wsl home directory

====================================

[image]

====================================

Repo1: [image]

====================================

Repo2: [image]

====================================

Would anyone know why the branch names are not appearing.

Comment: Is it a detached HEAD in Repo 2?

Comment: @ElpieKay
No, pointing to a branch which just doesn't get displayed.

Comment: First step is to figure out whether they are supposed to be shown with Zsh and with that setup.

Comment: @Guildenstern They are, supposed to come out of the box,I kept re-configuring the p10k theme, installed all necessary fonts, able to see all the icons, however no luck.

Comment: Found the issue relating to the homedir.

Had to do with the below line in my.p10k.zsh

 typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_DISABLED_WORKDIR_PATTERN='~'

Commenting it out fixed it.

Still no luck on the alternative worktree branchnames not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I'll display my findings and close this question.

1. Home directory branch not showing:

   Commenting out this line in my.p10k.zsh solved the issue

   typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_DISABLED_WORKDIR_PATTERN='~'
2. Git worktree branch name not showing.

   Not yet supported as discussed [here](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/816)
   and [here](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/2312)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the default behavior of zsh. Follow instructions from git documentation to enable showing of git branch names:

https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh

> Zsh happens to be fairly compatible with Bash when it comes to prompt
> customization, but it allows you to have a right-side prompt as well.
> To include the branch name on the right side, add these lines to your
> ~/.zshrc file:
>
> ```
> setopt prompt_subst
> . ~/git-prompt.sh
> export RPROMPT=$'$(__git_ps1 "%s")'
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but

it doesn't seem like a solution. Still not able to see them.

Comment: @Artexias Did you try also "oh-my-zsh" mentioned in the above posted link?

Comment: Yes, I already have it installed with a p10k theme.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the dumb question, but can i know what did you do in the end? I'm wondering how can we still use p10k and revert worktree?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi ,what do you mean revert a worktree? You can still do any operations on a worktree as you would normally do, the only missing item would be the branch name next to the worktrees.